# NP-hardness of a variation of the bin packing problem

Tags: algorithms, reductions, np-hard

I was wondering if a variation of the bin packing problem where the 'size' of a bin is calculated as the product of item sizes in a bin instead of their sum is NP-hard. It seems like it must be, but I don't know how to prove it.

More formally, the problem is as follows:

Given a list of positive integer item sizes $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n$ and a positive integer $x$, find the smallest positive integer $k$ such that it is possible to partition the items into $k$ disjoint sets $S_1, S_2, ..., S_k$ such that the product of sizes in each $S_i$ is $\leq x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bin packing problem is [strongly NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem#Hardness_of_bin_packing). That means that even if the sizes are given in unary, the problem is still NP-hard.

In your case, your product-bin packing is equivalent to sum-bin packing, using $\log a_i$ and $\log x$ as sizes, and it is still NP-hard.